# Create user function for ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create a function to edit the look of a ggplot.

Here is a example of what I would like to create with a function (obviously the function I am trying to create is more complex, but this is for demonstration).

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
group_by(iris, Species) %>%
  summarise(m = mean(Sepal.Width)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Species, y = m)) +
  geom_col() + 
  xlab("") + ylab("")
```

Here is the function I am trying to make:

```
name_axis <- function(){
  xlab(label = "") + 
  ylab(label = "")   
}

group_by(iris, Species) %>%
  summarise(m = mean(Sepal.Width)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Species, y = m)) +
  geom_col() + 
  name_axis()
```

I know I could just do this by first save the plot to a object and then pass the plot to the new function. But I want to skip that step and use the "+" instead.

Comment: So, you want the axes to show no labels at all?

Comment: Yes in this example. I am trying to create a family of 'look-functions' for ggplot to standardize looks. So one function will have arguments for names of the axis, and if the y-axis should show percents or not etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that with

1. a `list()`:

```
    name_axis <- list(
      xlab(label = "Nothing"),  
      ylab(label = ""))

    group_by(iris, Species) %>%
      summarise(m = mean(Sepal.Width)) %>%
      ggplot(aes(x = Species, y = m)) +
      geom_col() + 
      name_axis
```

2. passing a list inside the function:

````
  name_axis <- function(){
      list(xlab(label = ""), 
        ylab(label = "hello"))   
    }

   group_by(iris, Species) %>%
      summarise(m = mean(Sepal.Width)) %>%
      ggplot(aes(x = Species, y = m)) +
      geom_col() + 
      name_axis()```
````

Comment: wow, okay, I did not know you could use lists for this task. Thanks a lot for that tip. This solved my problem. Thank you.